# Javascript toLowerCase() giving different length with non-Latin characters

Tags: javascript, text, unicode

Why JS has problem with capitalized i (**İ**) while javascript is ok with capitalized ş,ö,ç,ğ,ü (**Ş**,**Ö**,**Ç**,**Ğ**,**Ü**), as stated below? (Problem is not related with the letter position.)

```
"İş".toLowerCase().length
3
"İŞ".toLowerCase().length
3
"iŞ".toLowerCase().length
2
"iş".toLowerCase().length
2
```

Moreover

```
"İ".length
1
"İ".toLowerCase().length
2
"İ".toLocaleLowerCase().length
2
```

For sceptics, here is screen shot of console where i copied the above codes:

[image]

and my charset (which is the first thing I've checked after this problem occurs):

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the character above capital `İ`<sup>←</sup>. That is another string value in javascript. You can use `.split();` to see the character counts. One more thing to notice it is not just about capital `İ` but `á` is also in those list.

You should use `String.prototype.toLocaleLowerCase()` to locale-specific case mappings.

```js
console.log("áş".toLocaleLowerCase().split(''));

console.log("İş".toLocaleLowerCase().split(''));
```

Comment: This taught me a lot but `"İ".length` is 1 while `"İ".toLowerCase().length` and `"İ".toLocaleLowerCase().length` are still 2. How come another string value (dot above İ) is considered as one char together with I, while `toLowerCase()` or `toLocaleLowerCase()` considering that as 2 char?

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk well in this case i am a bit stumped. but there might be some internal issues against locales.